# Linearized Pitot system

Tags: derivatives, linearization

I am trying to create a linearized model of a compressible pitot tube system with altitude $h$ as the input and velocity as the output.

When I take the derivative and try and linearize around a point the derivative does not match (approximately) the delta between two points around it.

I have pitot tube velocity equation:

$T(h) =$ Temperature

$P(h) =$ static pressure

$P_o =$ stagnation pressure

------------------------------Constants-------------------------------

$P_s = 101$ KPa

$T_o = 290$ K

$\gamma = 1.4$

$M = 0.0289644$

----------------------- Governing Equations------------------------

$P = P_se^\frac{h*g*M}{RT}$

$ T = T_o-.0065*h$

$Mach = \sqrt{\frac{2}{(\gamma-1)}\biggr((\frac{P_o}{P(h)})^\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}-1\biggr)}$

$a = \sqrt{\gamma RT}$

$v = Mach*a$

My approach was to take the derivative (using chain rule) and add that to the nominal point

$dv = \frac{dv}{dT}\frac{dT}{dh} + \frac{dv}{dP}\frac{dP}{dh}$

so that:

$v = v_{nom} + dv$

I'm not sure about my method or my derivation using the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$
P -P_se^\frac{h*g*M}{RT} = 0\\
M - \sqrt{\frac{2}{(\gamma-1)}\biggr(\left(\frac{P_o}{P(h)}\right)^\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}-1\biggr)}= 0
$$

$$
f_1(P,M,h)=0\\
f_2(P,M,h)=0
$$

then

$$
\frac{df_1}{dh}=\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial P}P'+\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial M}M'+\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial h}=0\\
\frac{df_2}{dh}=\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial P}P'+\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial M}M'+\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial h}=0
$$

and solving for $P', M'$ we have

$$
P' = \frac{2 g (\gamma -1)^2 M(h) P(h) \left(T(h)-h T'(h)\right) \sqrt{\frac{\left(\frac{\text{P0}}{P(h)}\right)^{\frac{\gamma }{\gamma -1}}-1}{\gamma
   -1}}}{T(h) \left(\sqrt{2} g \gamma  h \left(\frac{P_0}{P(h)}\right)^{\frac{\gamma }{\gamma -1}}+2 (\gamma -1)^2 R T(h)
   \sqrt{\frac{\left(\frac{P_0}{P(h)}\right)^{\frac{\gamma }{\gamma -1}}-1}{\gamma -1}}\right)}\\
M' = -\frac{\sqrt{2} g \gamma  M(h) \left(T(h)-h T'(h)\right) \left(\frac{\text{P0}}{P(h)}\right)^{\frac{\gamma }{\gamma -1}}}{T(h) \left(\sqrt{2} g
   \gamma  h \left(\frac{P_0}{P(h)}\right)^{\frac{\gamma }{\gamma -1}}+2 (\gamma -1)^2 R T(h)
   \sqrt{\frac{\left(\frac{P_0}{P(h)}\right)^{\frac{\gamma }{\gamma -1}}-1}{\gamma -1}}\right)}
$$

Comment: Was looking at your equations, and the Pressure derivative seemed strange to me. I double checked and realized I did not properly clarify the M in pressure equation was molar mass. I apologize for that. 

I was wondering if you could explain the equations after "then" in your answer? The notation is somewhat unfamiliar with me.

Comment: @Boto After then,  follows the chain rule applied in the total derivation for $f_1, f_2$ regarding the variable $h$, knowing that $M = M(h)$ and $P = P(h)$ Now according to  your modifications the result  is not more  correct because $M \ne Macht$

Comment: Ok, maybe I am interpreting it incorrectly, but given that it $f_1$ appears to be the function of pressure, wouldn't taking the derivative of $f_1$ with respect to $P$ be the same as $P'$ ? Chain rule has always been a bit fuzzy for me which has been part of the issue I've had with this problem.